# How can I make a background service for timer without showing a notification?

Tags: java, android

I have tried many solution but useless, all say use foreground service.

is there a way to **trick** android or to use a proper way.

i know it's restriction from android to inform the user that an app is draining the battery without using it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is use a foreground service.  You can't have a background service for more than 2 minutes on modern Android.

Now if your timer is long (say 1 minute+) an alarm instead of a timer would work better.  That wouldn't require a service, its a broadcast and your app would be restarted to handle it.  Of course if you go into Doze those are still limited.